# Using a HandlerInterceptor to add model attributes with Spring Web Flow

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-webflow-2

I have a HandlerInterceptor to add some "global" model variables. It works.

Now, I try to reuse it in Spring Web Flow, for the same reason.

**But** HandlerInterceptors have the ModelAndView parameter set to NULL under Spring Web Flow (couldn't figure why, but it's a fact).

I have referenced my interceptor in the FlowHandlerMapping bean :

```
<bean class="org.springframework.webflow.mvc.servlet.FlowHandlerMapping"> 
    <property name="order" value="0" /> 
    <property name="flowRegistry" ref="flowRegistry" />
    <property name="interceptors">
        <list>
            <ref bean="myInterceptor" />
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

How can I add variables to the model ?

Is there a workaround, with the request parameter for example ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Starting with Spring Webflow 2, the `ModelAndView` object is not generated anymore (see [this post](http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?66246-ModelAndView-getting-null-in-post-handle-interceptor-while-upgrading-webflows&p=295756#post295756) (and thread) at the SpringSource forum).

---

The `FlowHandlerAdapter` handle() function does not generate a ModedAndView anymore (it just returns null) even if this function is :

```
public ModelAndView handle(HttpServletRequest request, 
        HttpServletResponse response, Object handler)
```

So overriding this function is pointless, but this function creates a `ServletExternalContext` object, which holds all the flow variable, by calling its method :

```
protected ServletExternalContext createServletExternalContext(
    HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
```

By overriding this function you can pretty much do what you want with this flow variables.

---

To do this, just create a class that extends `FlowHandlerAdapter`, register it instead of FlowHandlerAdapter and override the `createServletExternalContext` function.

Basically you use `ServletExternalContext.getSessionMap()` to access a `SharedAttributeMap` and register your properties.

As you have access to the `HttpServletRequest` and `HttpServletResponse` objects, this method can act petty much like a `HandlerInterceptorAdapter.postHandle` function.

See an example below.

I left out how to use generic way to reuse the same code for a `HandlerInterceptor` for the MVC and this object but it's easy to code, by implementing `HandlerInterceptor`.

---

MyFlowHandlerAdapter :

```
package my.package;
public class MyFlowHandlerAdapter extends FlowHandlerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected ServletExternalContext createServletExternalContext(
            HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) {

        ServletExternalContext context = 
            super.createServletExternalContext(request,response);

        context.getSessionMap().put("myproperty", "myvalue");

        return context;
    }
}
```

You have the `FlowHandlerAdapter` object defined in you webflow-context.xml file like that :

```
<bean class="org.springframework.webflow.mvc.servlet.FlowHandlerAdapter">
    <property name="flowExecutor" ref="flowExecutor"/>
</bean>
```

Just replace it with :

```
<bean class="my.package.MyFlowHandlerAdapter">
    <property name="flowExecutor" ref="flowExecutor"/>
</bean>
```

Comment: hi i have a issues in integration of interceptor in spring web flow can  you help me .

Answer (score 0):

`ModelAndView` can be null when the interceptor is processing an Ajax request.

Just check if `ModelAndView` is *null*. If not, that's because the interceptor is processing a view-model, so you can add your variables at this time.

Comment: NO controller : it's a Web Flow ! :-)

Comment: Actually, I found a "clean" workaround : I created a @Service annotated class which is called by the HandlerInterceptor for MVC components, and inside the flow for SWF components. This somehow avoids code duplication.